# how to add a confirmation box on my contact form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup, confirmation

im new in programming and im making my first site, well lets get to the point.
Below is my actual HTML code for a symple contact form

```html
          <form class="row form" id="contacto" name="contacto" method="post" action="enviar.php">
                <h3>Formulario de Contacto</h3>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="nombre">Name</label>
                    <input name="nombre" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre">
                </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                    <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="telefono">telefono</label>
                    <input name="telefono" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Telefono" id="telefono">
                </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="ciudad">ciudad</label>
                    <input name="ciudad" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Ciudad" id"ciudad">
                </div>
                
                </div>
            </form> <!-- /.row -->
  </div> <!-- /.container -->
 </section> <!-- /.contact -->
```

I want to add a confirmation popup when i click the submit button that says (your message has been sent)
I appreciate all help that you guys can bring. :)

Comment: That should only be done when the form is actually submitted in PHP. `if (mail()) { /* display message */ }`

Comment: See my answer... add a button and that's it

Comment: You need an alert or open a new windows with such message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="alert('your message has been sent');" />
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution: add a button within the form tags of type submit with an onclick defined:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return doit();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doit() {
        alert("your message has been sent!");
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why so complicated? It can be done with 6 line less

Comment: Well, adding javascript into javascript tags and just call functions into the html seems to me cleaner... I have the scrollbar you know ;)

Comment: If the task was more more complicated, then I would agree with you. But in this particular case, I believe that a single line is the best solution.